# Read all of Hubspot contacts with API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, hubspot

I'm trying to create a DF with all of my Hubspot contacts, however the max read size for the API is 100 contacts at a time.

I am currently using this API call to pull data from Hubspot:

```
import hubspot
from pprint import pprint
from hubspot.crm.contacts import ApiException

client = hubspot.Client.create(api_key="API")

try:
    api_response = client.crm.contacts.basic_api.get_page(limit=100, archived=False)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling basic_api->get_page: %s\n" % e)
```

Is there a way for me to loop through this API call to get all of the contacts and then exit the loop at the end if the contact list is empty?

Comment: normally, the API response will contain some metadata, telling you how many pages there are and how many times you need to hit the API based on the limits. What's in the response?

Comment: This is at the top of my reponse: `{'paging': {'next': {'after': '193102',
                     'link': 'LINK'}}`

Comment: so you need to follow the `next` link in the api response, so you need to either loop and hit the next repsonse or use an async method. I'd refer to the docs though they are super detailed.